# android: creat layout dynamically and setContentView it dynamically

Tags: java, android

Suppose there is an `Activity` called "m1" and there are two layouts called "m2" and "m3" both have few buttons is dynamically how i can setContentView  dynamically whay

Comment: why dont use fragment? i dont get "both have few buttons is dynamically"

Comment: Why you need two layouts ?? You should have one view for single activity and define all of your views in it. On runtime, you can hide or visible views according to your conditions

Comment: [simple setContentView tutorial](https://androidride.com/what-setcontentview-android-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a method to set view to the [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

So you can pass the root parent view to this method to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass layout Resource ID or View in `setContentView();` method.

try this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(viewlayout1){
      view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1,null);
    }else{
      view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2,null);
    }
    setContentView(view);

    /*******************/

 }
```

Comment: tanks its work this way i can load activity dynamically

Answer (score 1):

The `view hierarchy` can have only one `root`. What `setContentView()` essentially does is that it sets the root view.

In your case,

**Method 1**

You'll have to either make **one of the layouts as the root**  and **add the other as a child**. And call `setContentView(root)`.

Or

**Method 2**

Create a dummy **container** layout. Set that as root.
And add both your layouts as children to that container layout.